# How can i display the number of comparisons made for linear search and binary search

Tags: c++

My assignment is to create a linear and binary search algorithm, and display the number of counts it takes to find the inputted value.

i have tried to use probes to count them but it gave me an error of lnk2019. What is another way of displaying the number of comparisons on the screen?

Here is the assignment:
 Write a program that has an array of at least 25 integers. It should call a function that uses the linear search algorithm to locate one of the values. The function should keep a count of the number of comparisons it makes until it finds the value. The program then should call a function that uses the binary search algorithm to locate the same value. It should also keep count of the number of comparisons it makes. Display these values on the screen.

`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int linearSearch(int a[], int size, int target);
int binarySearch(const int array[], int size, int value);



int main(void)
{
//linear search
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 };

int result;
int userNum;

cout << "enter any number between 1 and 25\n";
cin >> userNum;

result = linearSearch(arr, 25, userNum);

if (result == -1)
    cout << "Not found in linear search\n";
else
    cout << "Linear search : Found at element " << result << endl;

//binary search
result = binarySearch(arr, 25, userNum);
    if (result == -1)
        cout << "Not found in binary search\n";
    else
    {
        cout << "Binary search : Found at element " << result << endl;
    }


return 0;

}


int linearSearch(int a[], int size, int target, int &numProbes)
{

int index = 0;
numProbes = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    numProbes++;
    if (target == a[index])
        return index;
return -1;
}

int binarySearch(const int array[], int size, int value, int &numProbes)
{
int first = 0,
    last = size - 1,
    middle,
    position = -1;
bool found = false;

numProbes = 0;
while (!found && first <= last)
{
    numProbes++;
    middle = (first + last) / 2;
    if (array[middle] == value)
    {
        found = true;
        position = middle;
    }
    else if (array[middle] > value)
        last = middle - 1;
    else first = middle + 1;
}
return position;
} `
```

Comment: "i have tried to use probes to count them but it gave me an error of lnk2019." this refers to the posted code? Please include the full error message in the question

Comment: All you need is a `int` that you initialize to zero and increment every time you do something you want to count and then print at the end.

Comment: Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl binarySearch(int const * const,int,int)" (?binarySearch@@YAHQBHHH@Z) referenced in function _main linear and binary C:\Users\Dylank\source\repos\linear and binary\Source.obj 1 

Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl binarySearch(int const * const,int,int)" (?binarySearch@@YAHQBHHH@Z) referenced in function _main linear and binary C:\Users\Dylank\source\repos\linear and binary\Source.obj 1

Comment: next time please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56499843/edit) your question, code in comments is almost impossible to read. For now, the error is because your declarations dont match the function definitions. You missed to add the `numProbes` parameter when you declare them at the top of your code. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: ...and of course you also have to pass the parameters. Actually now I wonder, did you write that code?

Comment: yes this is my code but i saw someone use this method and gave it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that the definition of your `binarySearch` function doesn't match it's declaration (you have one more parameter in definition).

The easiest solution is to move the `main()` function to the end of the file and get rid of the declaration of your functions, thus getting clear error messages on the compilation phase.

Comment: Or just fix the declarations.